# Can't set css transform for icon on here map

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to rotate icon marker using H.map.DomMarker :

```
var domElement = document.createElement('img');
    domElement.src = 'green-dot.png';
    domElement.style.transform='matrix(1, -0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0)';
    domElement.style.webkitTransform='matrix(1, -0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0)';
    domElement.style.msTransform='matrix(1, -0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0)';
var domIcon = new H.map.DomIcon(domElement, {});
var marker = new H.map.DomMarker(coordinate, {
    icon: domIcon
 });
```

But i show console, it's different :
[image: Transform css icon marker here map]
How can i override css tranform for icon in here map ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution : create a div tag wrap img tag like :

```
var domElementFather = document.createElement('div');
domElementFather.appendChild(domElement);
var domIcon = new H.map.DomIcon(domElementFather, {});
```

And it's just show css like:

```
transform : rotate(40deg)
```